# How to Keep Syntax Color but Disable Highlighting in Vim?

Tags: linux, vim, ubuntu-18.04, syntax-highlighting

I recently activated auto-complete and syntax color in Vim. However, a red highlighting color appeared.

[image]

I tried to disable syntax color with `syntax off`, but this highlighting color is still there.

[image]

Here's my `~/.vimrc`

```c
    syntax on
    
    set nocompatible             " be iMproved, required
    filetype on                  " required
    
    " set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
    set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
    call vundle#begin()
    " alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
    "call vundle#begin('~/some/path/here')
    
    " let Vundle manage Vundle, required
    Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
    Plugin 'ycm-core/YouCompleteMe'
    
    " The following are examples of different formats supported.
    " Keep Plugin commands between vundle#begin/end.
    " plugin on GitHub repo
    Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
    " plugin from http://vim-scripts.org/vim/scripts.html
    " Plugin 'L9'
    " Git plugin not hosted on GitHub
    Plugin 'git://git.wincent.com/command-t.git'
    " git repos on your local machine (i.e. when working on your own plugin)
    Plugin 'file:///home/gmarik/path/to/plugin'
    " The sparkup vim script is in a subdirectory of this repo called vim.
    " Pass the path to set the runtimepath properly.
    Plugin 'rstacruz/sparkup', {'rtp': 'vim/'}
    " Install L9 and avoid a Naming conflict if you've already installed a
    " different version somewhere else.
    " Plugin 'ascenator/L9', {'name': 'newL9'}
    
    " All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
    call vundle#end()            " required
    filetype plugin indent on    " required
    " To ignore plugin indent changes, instead use:
    "filetype plugin on
    "
    " Brief help
    " :PluginList       - lists configured plugins
    " :PluginInstall    - installs plugins; append `!` to update or just :PluginUpdate
    " :PluginSearch foo - searches for foo; append `!` to refresh local cache
    " :PluginClean      - confirms removal of unused plugins; append `!` to auto-approve removal
    "
    " see :h vundle for more details or wiki for FAQ
    " Put your non-Plugin stuff after this line
    :set number
```

It's hard to see my code with color highlights. I want to keep the syntax color, but without the highlighting. I couldn't find the setting in `~/.vimrc`. How do I disable this ?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this is from auto-completion. As mentioned in [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe#the-gycm_show_diagnostics_ui-option) github about Diagnostic UI,

This turns on YCM's diagnostic display features including like the gutter signs, **text highlighting**, diagnostic echo and auto location list population. To disable this, I put :

```
let g:ycm_show_diagnostics_ui = 1
```

and the highlights are gone.

[image]